# Torrent via tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, bittorrent

Can't I download files of more than 1 GB via configured tor?

I'm using socksv5 127.0.0.1 and port 9150.
I've already downloaded files of less than 1 GB and they downloaded just fine. However, when I tried to download files of more than a 1 GB it was stuck at connecting to peers.

Comment: To add to the comment of @jamescampbell, the Tor project not only recommends not using Tor to download torrent, it asks specifically that you do not. There are two reasons for the request: first, it uses valuable bandwidth; second, it affords you no real protection because the BitTorrent protocol itself reveals your IP ... so the bandwidth that is taken from other users who want to remain anonymous ends up being used for a purpose that destroys anonymity.

Answer (score 1):

Using tor should not affect that at all. However, you should consider using a private VPN for that instead of consuming resources on a limited network.

Answer (score 0):

Tor really recommends against using the Tor network for downloading torrents. [see the blog post here](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/bittorrent-over-tor-isnt-good-idea).